# Path to file in azure project

Tags: azure, filepath, emgucv

I have a problem with azure WCF project. I want to get file path to xml file which I add to project <**add** -> **existing item**>. In its properties I set "**Copy if newer**" and when i deploy it on azure server I see that this file is beeing correctly copied to **bin**.
I have tried do use:

1) This one is working only locally on emulator:

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RoleRoot"), @"approot", @"bin", @"myFile.xml");
```

2) Is not working anywhere (on emulator and azure):

```
string appRoot = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\"); 
string filePath = Path.Combine(appRoot + @"\", @"bin\myFile.xml");
```

Maybe there is another way than adding xml file to output directory? I am using EmguCV and would like to load cascade xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Azure is nothing special! It is just IIS! So whatever you do locally and works, will work in Azure too (as a general rule of thumb).

Have you tried `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bin/name_of_file.xml");`?

I also wonder why would you set its `Copy Local` attribute. The correct way of adding XML to a solution is to make it's `Build Action` to `Content` and `Copy to Output` to `Do not copy`. Then just `Server.MapPath("~/name_of_file.xml")` should be OK.

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath doesn't work on azure

Comment: how did you come to that conclusion ?!

Comment: if you access your web app via ftp, you'll find two directories wwwroot and repository, both having almost the same files. The exception is that repository is containing only public files, so for example if you save files in some folder from the code, you'll not find that file in repository but you'll find it in wwwroot. And because MapPath returns the path of the repository, you will get errors if you try to reference a file saved from code for example.

Comment: your are wrong. Server.MapPath() always return path relative to your AppDomain root folder. And your application is started from the WWWROOT. The repository directory is there **only** if you enable local GIT for the web app, or if you integrate with external source control (which automatically creates local git repository).

Answer (score 1):

I just went through this trying to get an Azure Function that works when run locally to work when deployed to Azure.  My function was referencing a data file that was located in my solution and not finding it when deployed to Azure.  While I was able to locate the file when running locally with just the filename, I had to use the path "D:\home\site\wwwroot\" for the file to be located in Azure.  Rather than using a hard-coded value for the path, I instead used:

```
var binPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))
```

which gets the path to the Azure function binaries, but my data file was in the parent folder, so:

```
var parentOfBinPath = new DirectoryInfo(binPath).Parent.FullName;
```

and combined with the filename to get a full file path:

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(parentOfBinPath, "my-file.dat");
```

which worked for both the locally run function and the function that was deployed to Azure.